# How to turn on/off a field from parsley.js form validation

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, parsley.js

[image]When validating an email field [name=bar] in a form #foo, I want to switch validation of that field on and off, in relation to a checkbox.

Reading the docs, github issues and stackoverflow answers, I thought setting data-parsley-required="false" and/or data-parsley-validate="false" would be enough.

But it turns out, that all other constraints, like email, min-lenght, max-length are still validated and the input field still validates to an error condition. I would prefer it to validate to success or not at all.

```
<form id="foo">
    <input name="bar"
           maxlength="40"
           value=""
           class="form-control"
           data-parsley-validate="false"
           data-parsley-required="false"
           type="email"
           data-parsley-minlength="5"
           data-parsley-trigger="input keyup change"
           data-parsley-error-message="something is wrong">
</form>
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/88obg0sj/9/

So how is it possible to turn off field validation in way, it can be re-activated again?

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/br3t/88obg0sj/10/ ?

Comment: You added the checkbox to the example. And when the checkbox is unchecked you call .parsley() to get the existing ParsleyField instance and .destroy() to destroy it. But when checked you do just .parsley(), which does not work for me, as I initially called $('form#foo').parsley({lotsOfOptions}) and also event subscriptions. And I guess, these options are all forgotten. So I would prefer to just do: if not checked, validate to true.

Answer (score 0):

You should tweak the `excluded` option, for example by adding `", [data-parsley-validate="false"]"` to it.

Comment: Idea sounds good, but I can't even get it excluded initially! Maybe it's only excluded on form submit, not on single field validation? https://jsfiddle.net/Lwdppsvm/2/

Comment: I can't come up with a working solutions for this. It's very hard to make a field just pass / validate as sucess or exclude. Can't imagine, it's such a strange use-case of mine.

Comment: And I am right, excluded does not have effect on single field validation triggered on input/change/keyup, but only on form submit, when all fields are validated: https://jsfiddle.net/Lwdppsvm/5/

Answer (score 0):

**You can follow this way:-**

```
//destroy parsley
$('form').parsley().destroy();

//set required attribute on input to false
$('input').attr('data-parsley-required', 'false');

//reinitialize parsley
$('form').parsley();
```